# 'System.AggregateException' when attempting to connect to my Common Data Service web api

Tags: c#, api, cds

Here is my code:

```
string url = "https://myOrg.api.crm.dynamics.com";
string apiVersion = "9.1";
string webApiUrl = $"{url}/api/data/v{apiVersion}/";
var authParameters = AuthenticationParameters.CreateFromResourceUrlAsync(new Uri(webApiUrl)).Result;
```

My last line of code is failing with:
[image]

The ouput is:

*MyAPITest.vshost.exe Error: 0 : 11/05/2019 19:20:17:  - AuthenticationParameters: System.ArgumentException: Unauthorized Http Status Code (401) was expected in the response
Parameter name: response
Exception thrown: 'System.AggregateException' in mscorlib.dll
The program '[5556] MyAPITest.vshost.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).*

For reference, I am attempting to use the [Quick Start Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/webapi/quick-start-console-app-csharp) to connect to the Common Data Service.

EDIT:
In looking at the details I am seeing:
[image]

Error

*The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occured on a send.*

More detail beneath that error:

*Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here was the problem, found in the guide:

[image]

I am running VS 2015.  Once I unchecked this, it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

> AuthenticationParameters: System.ArgumentException: Unauthorized Http Status Code (401) was expected in the response

The error is typically because it's lacking valid authentication credentials and the request has not been applied for the target resource.

Also if you don't know, the `AuthenticationParameters.CreateFromResourceUrlAsync` API is **obsolete**, [read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.authenticationparameters.createfromresourceurlasync?view=azure-dotnet) more there.

With this in mind, I would look into using [AuthenticationParameters.CreateFromUrlAsync(Uri) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.authenticationparameters.createfromurlasync?view=azure-dotnet) in which should be used. It sends a GET request to the url provided with no `Authenticate header`. *If a 401 Unauthorized is received*, this helper will parse the WWW-Authenticate header to retrieve the authority and resource.